# Unable to sync NTP v4 client to Windows AD server

Tags: solaris, ntpd

I realize that Microsoft doesn't even recommend using a windows server as a time service, however I don't have a choice -- closed network in a windows centric shop.

It became an issue when the newer Solaris 11 systems could not sync to the AD servers which come with NTP v4 ( 4.2.8p10 ).

It does work for the Solaris 10 servers using the older v3 (xntpd) as a client.  I tried disabling the older client, and enabling the ntp4 client ( 4.2.8p9) on the Solaris 10 systems.  So even though it had been working, and uses the same ntp.conf, the v4 client fails to sync.

Anyone have any suggestions on a possible tweak to sync a NTP v4 client to a Windows 2012 R2 AD server?

**ntp.conf**

```
server AD_SVR1_IP prefer iburst
server      AD_SVR2_IP
peer        rac-node2
```

My long term plan is to get the network team to enable a NTP service on one of their device that we all point to.

Thanks

Comment: How far towards "not syncing" do they get? Is NTP traffic allowed there & back? Is the Windows server being excluded for some reason (false ticker, etc)?

Comment: They're all in the same subnet and have no firewall between them.  Also, no issues in the case when using the v3 client on Solaris 10.

The tally code is a space for the two AD servers, as well as any Solaris peers.  In the case of the later, the logs indicate that the peer's stratum is too high.

Comment: `ntpq -np AD_SVR1_IP` please. And `ntpq -np` on the Solaris client. Also, what if you remove the `prefer` keyword?

Comment: Removing prefer has no effect.

Comment: Issuing cmd against AD servers gives: "timed out, nothing received"  But I also see the same error running the command from a Solaris 10 server using the older ntp client.
Issuing it against another Solaris server shows what you'd see if you ran ntpq -p on that server.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on a Linux-based system running `ntpd` version 4.2.6p5, talking to a Windows 2012 R2 running as a Domain Controller. (I don't have access to Solaris.)

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

server AD_SERVER1 iburst
server AD_SERVER2 iburst
server AD_SERVER3 iburst

restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
```